# Convert string in to dictionary

Tags: python, json, serialization, dictionary, pickle

I know It's looks like a dumb question, but anyway.

I'm trying to convert string representation of dictionary back in to dictionary.

My workflow is the following:

```
d = {1:2}
s = str(d)
```

When I do:

```
dict(s)
```

I get:

> > ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

And when I do:

```
json.loads(s)
```

I get this:

> > ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)

How do I convert it back to a dictionary?

### UPDATE:

I should mention, that the actual data is the following:

> {'cell_num': u'', 'home_num': u'16047207276', 'registration_country':
>   u'US', 'registration_ip': u'71.102.221.29', 'last_updated':
>   datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 27, 15, 41, 59), 'address': {'country':
>   u'US', 'state': u'CA', 'zip': u'', 'city': u'Santa Barbara', 'street':
>   u'', 'confirmed': False, 'created': datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 24, 10,
>   23), 'updated': datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 24, 10, 23)},
>   'old_home_num': u'16047207276', 'old_cell_num': u''}

In that case, option with `json.loads` and `ast.literal_eval()` are not appropriate. 
So I went further and tried to deserialize it with pickle standard python library.

> import pickle
>
> pickle.loads(data)

But then I get:

> KeyError: '{'

Comment: You never call `obj.__str__()` directly - use `str(obj)` instead. However, that's not what you want here either way :)

Comment: Use the `json` module instead...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a portable string representation, use `s = json.dumps(d)` which can then be reloaded using `json.loads(s)`

However, this is limited to JSON-compatible types. If you just want to use it within python the most powerful option is [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) (be careful: never unpickle untrusted data!).

To create a string loadable using `pickle.loads()` you need to create it from the original object using `pickle.dumps()` (i.e. just like you'd do with `json` but with `pickle` instead).

However, if you already have that string you posted, you could use [`eval(s)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate it as a python expression. This is usually a bad idea though and using a repr only works for objects which actually have a repr that is valid python code.

Comment: Actually data is follow: {'cell_num': u'', 'home_num': u'16047207276', 'registration_country': u'US', 'registration_ip': u'71.102.221.29', 'last_updated': datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 27, 15, 41, 59), 'address': {'country': u'US', 'state': u'CA', 'zip': u'', 'city': u'Santa Barbara', 'street': u'', 'confirmed': False, 'created': datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 24, 10, 23), 'updated': datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 24, 10, 23)}, 'old_home_num': u'16047207276', 'old_cell_num': u''}

Comment: Ok, so it's not JSON-compatible because of the datetime. Pickle is the easiest solution.

Comment: It is unicode. And `json.loads()` returns me unicode as well.

Answer (score 7):

Try using [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html), it's the safest way:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval('{1:2}')
=> '{1:2}'
```

From the linked documentation:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

Comment: Actually data is follow: `{'cell_num': u'', 'home_num': u'16047207276', 'registration_country': u'US', 'registration_ip': u'71.102.221.29', 'last_updated': datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 27, 15, 41, 59), 'address': {'country': u'US', 'state': u'CA', 'zip': u'', 'city': u'Santa Barbara', 'street': u'', 'confirmed': False, 'created': datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 24, 10, 23), 'updated': datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 24, 10, 23)}, 'old_home_num': u'16047207276', 'old_cell_num': u''}`

Comment: In your case I got different error:
`ValueError: malformed string`

Comment: I think that's such a nice solution.

Comment: @Pol it's because of the `datetime` objects, `literal_eval()` seems to have trouble parsing them. If the dictionary was made up of simple data types, my solution would be preferred. But alas, it won't work for you actual data :(

Comment: @Pol Perhaps you should put that data in the question itself since it seems relevant to giving the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pickle

pickle.loads(data)
```

This thing saved me once in the past.